PyQt How to edit only one specific table (QTableView) cell
There is a table that is not editable or even focusable.
By pressing the first button:

The table is unlocked
A certain table cell (let, for example, (1,1)) becomes available for editing

By pressing the second button, all prohibitions are canceled again.
How to implement the task?
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
import pandas as pd



table_data = [['parameter 1', '111', '222'],
            ['parameter 2', '333', '444'],
            ['parameter 3', '555', '666'],
            ['parameter 4', '777', '888']]


class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        data =  pd.DataFrame(table)
        self._data = data
    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]
    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None
    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None


class MyTable(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, model:QAbstractTableModel, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
        self.model = model
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.model = model(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Parameters', 'Existing', 'Acceptable']))
        self.setModel(self.model)
        # to disable a focus
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        # to disable select & edit
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        t  = MyTable(PandasModel, table_data)
        edit_cell_button = QPushButton('to allow to edit cell')
        edit_cell_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_edit_cell_button)
        disable_access_table_button = QPushButton('to deny to edit cell')
        disable_access_table_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_disable_access_table_button)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(t)
        vbox.addWidget(edit_cell_button)
        vbox.addWidget(disable_access_table_button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    # to allow access (select & edit) to table
    def handle_edit_cell_button(self):
        pass

    # to deny access to table
    def handle_disable_access_table_button(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())````


I tried but got a little confused.

You can set the whole view editable/not editable with setEditTriggers. You can make specific cells editable by returning ItemIsEditable from the model's flags() method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76802180/how-can-i-make-a-qsqltablemodel-read-only/76802481#76802481

Use edit() to start editing of a cell (but ensure you call setCurrentIndex() too). Note that editable indexes should return Qt.ItemFlags.ItemIsEditable from flags(), and you should also implement setData() in the model.

Does this answer your question? How can i make a QSqlTableModel read-only?
